# XNA 2D convert a world position into screen position

Tags: xna, position, screen, 2d

Okay guys, I have spent a good two weeks trying to figure this out. I've tried some of my own ways to work this out by math alone and had no success. I also looked everywhere and have seen people recommend `Viewport.Project()`.

This is not that simple. Everywhere I've looked, including MSDN areas and all forums, just suggest to be able to use it but as I try and use it they don't explain the matrix and values it requires to work. I have found no useful information on how to correctly use this method and it's seriously driving me insane. Please help this poor fella out.

First thing Im going to do is post my current code. I have five or so different versions none of them have worked. The closest I got was getting NAN which I don't understand. I'm trying to have text displayed on my screen based on where asteroids are and if they are very far the text will act as a guide so players can go to asteroids.

```
Vector3 camLookAt = Vector3.Zero;
Vector3 up = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

float nearClip = 1000.0f;
float farClip = 100000.0f;
float viewAngle = MathHelper.ToRadians(90f);
float aspectRatio = (float)viewPort.Width / (float)viewPort.Height;

Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), camLookAt, up);
Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(viewAngle, aspectRatio, nearClip, farClip);

Matrix world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(camPosition.X, camPosition.Y, 0);

Vector3 projectedPosition = graphicsDevice.Viewport.Project(new Vector3(worldPosition.X, worldPosition.Y, 0), projection, view, Matrix.Identity);

screenPosition.X = projectedPosition.X;
screenPosition.Y = projectedPosition.Y;


if (screenPosition.X > 400) screenPosition.X = 400;
if (screenPosition.X < 100) screenPosition.X = 100;
if (screenPosition.Y > 400) screenPosition.Y = 400;
if (screenPosition.Y < 100) screenPosition.Y = 100;
return screenPosition;
```

As far as I know Project is the camera position. My game is 2D so vector3 is annoying I thought maybe my Z could be CameraZoom, projection might be the object we want to convert to 2D Screen, view might be the size of how much the camera can see, and the last one I'm not sure.

After about 2 weeks of searching for information with no possible improvements in code or knowledge and being more confused as I look at MDSN tutorials I decided I'd post a question because I'm extremely close to just not implementing world position convert to screen position. All help is appreciated thanks :)

Plus I'm using a 2D game and it does add confusion when most times people talk about the Z axis when a 2D game does not have a Z axis its just transforming sprites to appear like a zoom or movement. Thanks again :)

Comment: So all you're trying to do is have a camera inside of a world in a 2d game?

Comment: i already have the camera setup, im trying to find the position of the 2D camera in a 2D world then convert that position of objects in the world to the screen coordinates to display text like a name or health over objects etc. P.S my camera has zooming also it can rotate but i dont use rotating

Comment: Wouldn't you just subtract the camera's world position from the object's world position to get the screen position?  Then you would need to account for zoom.  What I've always done is just assign a world position to everything (except the hud), then translate that into a screen position at render time (I wrote custom draw commands that used world position instead of screen position)..

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding here, but I don't think you need to be using a 3D camera provided with XNA for a 2D game.  Unless you're trying to make a 2.5D game using 3D for some sort of parallax system or whatever, you don't need to use that at all.  Take a look at these:

[2D Camera Implemetation in XNA](http://www.paradeofrain.com/tutorials/xna-camera-2d/)

[Simpler 2D Camera](http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/)

[XNA 2D tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx)

2D in XNA works differently than 3D. You don't need to worry about the 3D viewport or a 3D camera or anything. There is no nearclipping or farclipping. 2D is well-handled in XNA and I think you are misunderstanding a bit how XNA works.

PS: You don't need to use Vector3s.  Instead, use Vector2s. I think you will find them much easier to work with in a 2D game. ^^

Comment: hey kevin wang the link to Simpler 2D camera is my camera :D but i changed the camera position from middle of the screen to 0,0 for getting mouse world coordinates ill keep reading the other tutorials and let u know though